# provide default objects in kubernetes namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

We have several namespaces in a kubernetes (openshift) cluster and we want to provide some default objects in every namespace in an automated way. If for some reason one of these default objects is deleted (or changed), it should be recreated automatically. 
In openshift this already happens with some serviceaccounts and secrets for these accounts, but it is not easily extendable if i'm not mistaking. E.g. the the 'builder' and 'deployer' serviceaccount are created and recreated automatically by openshift. We are looking for a similar solution that supports all types of objects.

Does anyone has an example of how to accomplish this? It is possible to watch the etcd for changes and react to these changes by creating/modifying objects, but i can't seem to find a good example to start with.